# Using Modulo? writing code that uses existing code

Tags: java, modulo

I have written code with a `for` loop that prints out multiples of a number entered up to 100. I now have to write a code (preferably with a `for` loop) using modulo to print out all integers other than the multiples printed in the existing code. For instance, if you enter 3 in this code, it will need to print out 1,2,4,5,7,8, etc. Everything but those multiples up to 100. I'm having a hard time seeing how to use modulo here. This is the existing code it's based on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a number between 2 and 10:");
        int inputValue = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = inputValue; i < 100; i += inputValue) {
            System.out.println(i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {  // going from 1 to 100, increment by 1
    if (i%inputValue  != 0) {  // if not a multiple of inputValue
        System.out.println(i);  // print it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++;) {
    if (i % inputValue != 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your initial value, your loop test, your increment and perform a modulo. That is this

```
for (int i = inputValue; i < 100; i += inputValue) {
    System.out.println(i + "");
}
```

should be something like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { // <-- change initial and increment values
    if (i % number == 0) continue; // <-- add this.
    System.out.println(i); // <-- remove counterproductive string concatenation.
}
```